# Child div not disappearing with visibility hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, visibility

My code involves having a div in another div, and when I set both of their visibilities to hidden, only the parent div disappears. In a debugging attempt, I tried to print out the visibility of the child div, and it has 'visibility: hidden'.

```
#popup {
    visibility: visible;
    margin: auto;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: black;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: .5%;
    padding-right: .5%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    left: 14.5%;
    top: 20px;
    width: 70%;
    height: 450px;
}
#redX {
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    transition: .2s color ease-out;
}

------------------------------------------------
    // how I control the styles in changePopupVisibility()
    var popup = document.getElementById('popup');
    var redX = document.getElementById('redX');

    var popupOpen = true;
------------------------------------------------

    // rX is a variable I use to paste redX in different functions.
    var rX = "<div id='redX' onClick='changePopupVisibility()'>X</div><br>";

------------------------------------------------
// How I change visibility when the X has been clicked
function changePopupVisibility() {
        popupOpen = !popupOpen;
        if (popupOpen) {
            redX.style.visibility = "visible";
            popup.style.visibility = "visible";
        }
        else {
            redX.style.visibility = "hidden";
            popup.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
}
```

In case this gets a little confusing, I've put a working version of what I mean on [my website](http://jackygames.com/Games/Left/index.html). Click the red X once and everything will disappear, but click the word "left" and try again and only the parent will disappear.

Thanks.

Comment: thisi is not a solution, just a question, since the code is a modal form that disappears when it is closed, have you not considered using `display:none` instead of setting visibility? With `visibility:hidden` the mdal form would still take space on the form, which is probably not desired.

Comment: can you add the complete html code too?

Comment: @MartinStaufcik That's perfect, it actually did solve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use: `display: none;` as it makes the element not displayed at all and has no effect on the layout, where as `visibility: hidden;` the element will be invisible but still occupies space in the layout.

Read:

[CSS Visibility Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

and more specifically:

[CSS Layout - The display property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively try marking opacity to 0 & 1, instead of visibility as hidden & visible, and apply it to parent div.
Using **visibility will preserve the dimension** in case you want to use the dimensions same, opacity will reflect the same result as visibility.

```
function changePopupVisibility() {
    popupOpen = !popupOpen;
    if (popupOpen) {
         popup.style.opacity= 1;
    }
    else {

        popup.style.opacity= 0;
    }
}
```